# Почему не правильно работает программа на JS

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать анимацию из фотографий, все работает, но почему то, чтобы анимация работала нужно постоянно нажимать на кнопку ***Start***, а не один раз нажать и цикл запустился

```js
let delay = 200;
ImageNum = 1;
Images = new Array();
help = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  Images[i] = new Image();
  Images[i].src = "s" + i + ".gif";
}

function animate() {
  if (help == 1) {
    document.animation.src = Images[ImageNum].src;
    ImageNum++;
    if (ImageNum > 10) {
      ImageNum = 1;
    }
  }
}

function start() {
  help = 1;
  animate();
}
```

```html
<img name="animation" id="animation" src="s1.gif" onLoad="setTimeout(animate(), delay)">

<form>
  <input TYPE="button" Value="Start" onClick="start()">
</form>
```

Comment: Заменить setTimeout на setInterval

Comment: Пробовал с ним, точно так же почему то

Comment: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", start);

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в script

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", start);
```